# Keep N occurrences of a single character in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have this string: `"a_b_c_d_restofthestring"` and I only want to keep (e.g.) 2 underscores. So,

```
 "a_b_cdrestofthestring"
 "abc_d_restofthestring"
```

Are both valid outputs.

My current implementation is:

```js
let str = "___sdaj___osad$%^&*";

document.getElementById('input').innerText = str;

let u = 0;
str = str.split("").reduce((output, c) => {
  if (c == "_") u++;
  return u < 2 || c != "_" ? output + c : output;
});

document.getElementById('output').innerText = str;
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

But I'd like to know if there's a *better* way...

Comment: You want to remove everything after the first two underscores?

Comment: `str = str.replace(/^(.*?_.*?_)(.*)$/,(_,a,b) => a+b.replace(/_/g,''))`

Comment: do you want all six possible strings with two of four underscores as result?

Comment: I'd change `str.split("")` to `[...str]`.

Comment: No, @shreyasminocha, I want to remove all underscores except two of them, no matter which ones. All other characters remain.

Comment: I just need one of those, no matter which one. Let's say the easiest to achieve, @NinaScholz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, but here's a one-liner regular expression that replaces all but the last two underscores from the input string.

```js
let input = "___sdaj___osad$%^&*";
let output = input.replace(/_(?=(.*_){2})/g, '');

console.log("input: " + input);
console.log("output: " + output);
```

This of course is not very generalized, and you'd have to modify the regular expression every time you wanted to say, replace a character other than underscore, or allow 3 occurrences. But if you're okay with that, then this solution has a bit less code to maintain.

---

**Update:** Here's an alternate version, that's fully generic and should perform a bit better:

```js
let input = "___sdaj___osad$%^&*";

function replace(input, char = '_', max = 2, replaceWith = '') {
  let result = "";
  const len = input.length;
  
  for (let i = 0, u = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let c = input[i];
    result += (c === char && ++u > max) ? replaceWith : c;
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log("input: ", input);
console.log("output: ", replace(input));
```

See this [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/replace-all-but-n-occurrences-of-character/1) analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a regular expression which looks for an underscore and a counter of the keeping underscores and replace all others.

```js
var string = "a_b_c_d_restofthestring",
    result = string.replace(/_/g, (c => _ => c && c-- ? _ : '')(2));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 Clever. Faster than my Regex solution (see updated jsPerf) probably because it doesn't require any backtracking, and it's easier to make generic.